# MongoDB find always returning true when something doesnt exist (even on an empty database)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

```
app.post('/sign-up', function (req, res) {
  let emailValid = validator.validate(req.body.email);
  let consent = req.body.consent ? true:false

  if(emailValid && consent) {
    const user = new UserModel({
      name: req.body.firstName,
      surname: req.body.surname,
      email: req.body.email
      })
      UserModel.find({'email': req.body.email}, function(notFound, found) {
        if(notFound) {
          user.save().then(item => {
            console.log('Saved successfully!');
            res.render('submitSuccess', {data: req.body});
          }).catch(err => {
            res.status(400).render('404');
          })
        } else if(found) {
          console.log('Exists');
          res.status(404).render('submitSuccess', {data:req.body});
        }
         else {
          res.status(404).render('404');
        }
      });  
    }
});
```

The intended functionality here is that if someone submits an email to the database that already exists, it does not then save a duplicate. However, it seems that found is returning true everytime, therefore nothing is getting saved.

Comment: First argument of callback function is error: `UserModel.find({'email': req.body.email}, function(error, found) { ...`. What's in the error? (`console.log(error)`). You have an error running the query.

Comment: Read the doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code:

```
app.post('/sign-up', function (req, res) {
let emailValid = validator.validate(req.body.email);
let consent = req.body.consent ? true : false

if (emailValid && consent) {
    const user = new UserModel({
        name: req.body.firstName,
        surname: req.body.surname,
        email: req.body.email
    })
    UserModel.find({ 'email': req.body.email }, function (err, found) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).end();
            return;
        }

        if (found.length == 0) {
            user.save().then(item => {
                console.log('Saved successfully!');
                res.render('submitSuccess', { data: req.body });
            }).catch(err => {
                res.status(400).render('404');
            })
        } else {
            console.log('Exists');
            res.status(404).render('submitSuccess', { data: req.body });
        }
    });
  }
});
```

What's in the `err`?

Comment: Ok I think I may have had a fundemental misunderstanding of what the find function returns. So it returns an array of effectively count, and if that count is > 0 it exists, and if not it doesnt?

Comment: You can also use the `count` function instead of `find`: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count